# Fortran 77 code with incompatible calling sequences - how to modularize in Fortran 90/95?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, fortran77

Consider the following "real world" legacy Fortran 77 code, which may well be illegal according to the standard, but works in real life with a wide range of compilers, and produces no compiler or linker warnings if each subroutine is compiled separately.

```
subroutine a
complex z(10)
call b(z)
call r1(z)
call r2(z)
end

subroutine b(z)
complex z(10)
c ... use complex arithmetic on z
end

subroutine r1(x)
real x(2,10)
c ... do something with real and imaginary parts
c ... real parts are x(1,*)
c ... imaginary parts are x(2,*)
end

subroutine r2(x)
real x(20)
c ... do something with real and imaginary parts
end
```

I want to re-package code in this style using Fortran 90/95 modules. The naïve approach of

```
module m
public a
private b, r1, r2
contains 

subroutine a
complex z(10)
call b(z)
call r1(z)
call r2(z) 
end subroutine a

subroutine b(z)
complex z(10)
c ... use complex arithmetic on z
end subroutine b

subroutine r1(x)
real x(2,10)
c ... do something with real and imaginary parts
c ... real parts are x(1,*)
c ... imaginary parts are x(2,*)
end subroutine r1

subroutine r2(x)
real x(20)
c ... do something with real and imaginary parts
end subroutine r2

end module m
```

doesn't compile, because (of course) the compiler can now see that subroutines r1 and r2 are called with the wrong argument type.

I need some ideas on how to fix this, with the minimum amount of rewriting of the existing code, and *without making duplicate copies of the data in memory* - the real-life size of the data is too big for that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/31590004.

Comment: My advice is to really clean the code when you are porting it from old to modern standards, unless there is a strong time constraints. Since those subroutines are privates anyway, go into it, change the arguments to be complex. Change one loop to 2 when it is necessary. It will pay on the long run.

Comment: In an ideal world I would agree with you, but rewriting a few hundred thousand lines of poorly documented legacy code (dating from the era of "structured programming not invented yet") isn't an attractive option in the real world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c_f_pointer() may be useful to get a `real(2,*)` pointer to a `complex(*)` array, but I am not sure whether passing the complex parameter (zconst(:)) to ctor() is really okay... (here I have used gfortran 4.4 & 4.8 and ifort 14.0, and to make the output more compact the array dimension is changed from 10 to 3.)

```
module m
    implicit none
contains

subroutine r1 ( x )
    real x( 2, 3 )

    print *
    print *, "In r1:"
    print *, "Real part = ",x( 1, : )
    print *, "Imag part = ",x( 2, : )
endsubroutine

subroutine r2 ( x )
    real x( 6 )

    print *
    print *, "In r2:"
    print *, "all elements = ", x( : )
endsubroutine

subroutine b ( z )
    complex :: z( 3 )
    real, pointer :: rp(:,:)

    rp => ctor( z, 3 )  !! to compare z and rp                                      
    print *
    print *, "In b:"
    print *, "1st elem = ", z( 1 ), rp( :, 1 )
    print *, "3rd elem = ", z( 3 ), rp( :, 3 )
endsubroutine

function ctor( z, n ) result( ret )   !! get real(2,*) pointer to complex(*)
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    integer :: n
    complex, target :: z( n )
    real, pointer :: ret(:,:)
    call c_f_pointer( c_loc(z(1)), ret, shape=[2,n] )
endfunction

endmodule

program main
    use m
    implicit none
    complex z(3)
    complex, parameter :: zconst(3) = [(7.0,-7.0),(8.0,-8.0),(9.0,-9.0)]

    z(1) = ( 1.0, -1.0 )
    z(2) = ( 2.0, -2.0 )
    z(3) = ( 3.0, -3.0 )

    call r1 ( ctor( z, 3 ) )
    call r1 ( ctor( zconst, 3 ) )

    call r2 ( ctor( z, 3 ) )
    call r2 ( ctor( zconst, 3 ) )

    call b ( z )
    call b ( zconst )
 endprogram
```

Comment: Omg the title of the question has "Fortran90/95"... If not appropriate please let me know.

Comment: The "equivalence" answer reminded me of the non-standard "Cray Fortran pointer" syntax, which is implemented pretty widely for compatibility, and does something very similar to your answer but with less code than your c_f_pointer solution. I'll leave the question open for now to see if any other ideas turn up. I said Fortran 90/95 because the parameter list checks when modularizing the code in 90/95 are the root cause of the issue. A Fortran 2003 solution is OK.

Comment: The actual arguments associated with the `z` dummy argument of `ctor` do not have the target attribute.  When execution of the function finishes, the pointer association status of any pointers associated with the dummy argument becomes undefined - i.e. there is no guarantee when the function completes that `ret` points to the thing you think it points to.  Further, there are constraints on the argument to C_F_POINTER that this code may violate, depending on whether things are interoperable.

Comment: Further to the first part of @IanH's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31345009.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. So in this case is it sufficient to simply attach the TARGET attribute to the actual (complex) argument in the caller side (like z in subroutine b()) or a local variable z(3) in the main program, so as to make the code conformable to the Fortran 2003 standard?

Comment: The "auto-targetting feature of F08" mentioned in the above link may be useful so I'll check it later. https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/544610

Answer (score 1):

Note the following suggestion has some retrogressive aspects.

In the example code in the question, the original source of the data is a local variable.  Such a local variable can appear in a storage association context by using an equivalence statement, and in such a context it is possible to treat a COMPLEX object as a pair of REAL objects.

```
module m
  public a
  private b, r1, r2
contains 
  subroutine a
    complex z(10)
    real r(size(z)*2)
    equivalence (z,r)
    call b(z)     ! pass complex array
    call r1(r)    ! pass real array
    call r2(r)    ! pass real  array
  end subroutine a

  subroutine b(z)
    complex z(10)
    ! ... use complex arithmetic on z
  end subroutine b

  subroutine r1(x)
    real x(2,10)
    ! ... do something with real and imaginary parts
    ! ... real parts are x(1,*)
    ! ... imaginary parts are x(2,*)
  end subroutine r1

  subroutine r2(x)
    real x(20)
    ! ... do something with real and imaginary parts
  end subroutine r2
end module m
```

Comment: That's a useful idea for a partial solution, but it doesn't work if variable `z` was passed as a parameter to subroutine `a`.  Apologies for forgetting that use-case in the original question!

Comment: Dummy arguments cannot participate in a storage association context (though the associated effective argument may be in such a context).  You will need to get the original object that corresponds to `z` into your example into the procedure via some other means, perhaps as a module variable or via COMMON.

Answer (score 1):

(This is perhaps more a comment than an answer, but you can't include formatted code in a comment).

@roygvib answered the question in standard fortran 2003.

The same idea can be coded more concisely using the non-standard "Cray Fortran pointer" syntax which is implemented in many compilers - for example the `-fcray-pointer` option in gfortran. The non-standard intrinsic function `loc` replaces `ctor`.

```
subroutine b ( z )
    complex :: z( 3 )

    real :: r( 2, 3 )
    pointer(zp, r)
    zp = loc(z)

    print *
    print *, "In b:"
    print *, "1st elem = ", z( 1 ), r( :, 1)
    print *, "3rd elem = ", z( 3 ), r( :, 3)
endsubroutine
```

Comment: Yeah, Cray pointer is very compact and if it works for this purpose, it looks very nice. I tried to learn Cray pointers many times, but gave up every time because I couldn't find good tutorial pages... (and eventually, Fortran pointers appeard in the standard). But IMHO, I hope there would be some more flexible syntax for "type casting" also in Fortran (although I guess it is intentionally not provided by the Standard).

Comment: Cray pointers were even nicer on the original Crays which had word-addressable hardware, and so `zp = zp + 1` meant the same as `zp++` in C. The irony is that I knew about Cray pointers back in the 1980s, but I had forgotten about them when I hit this problem until the answers reminded me!