# Definition of operator(+) with multiple addends in Fortran with derived type. An issue with allocatable array

Tags: oop, fortran, operator-overloading, gfortran, derived-types

I am trying to define the (+) operator between Fortran derived types that describe matrices (linear operators).
My goal is to  implicitly define a matrix M = M1 + M2 + M3 such that, given a vector x, M*x = M1*x + M2*x + M3*x.

First, I defined an abstract type (abs_linop) with the abstract interface for a matrix vector multiplication (y = M *x).
Then, I built an derived type (add_linop), extending the abstract type (abs_linop).
The operator (+) is defined for the type (add_linop). I then create an example of concrete type (eye) extending the abstract type (abs_linop) that describes the identity matrix. This type is used in the main program. This is the source code

```
module LinearOperator
  implicit none
  private
  public :: abs_linop,multiplication
  type, abstract :: abs_linop   
     integer :: nrow=0
     integer :: ncol=0
     character(len=20) :: name='empty'
   contains
     !> Procedure for computation of (matrix) times (vector)
     procedure(multiplication), deferred :: Mxv
  end type abs_linop

  abstract interface
     !>-------------------------------------------------------------
     !> Abstract procedure defining the interface for a general
     !<-------------------------------------------------------------
     subroutine multiplication(this,vec_in,vec_out,info,lun_err)
       import abs_linop
       implicit none
       class(abs_linop), intent(inout) :: this
       real(kind=8), intent(in   ) :: vec_in(this%ncol)
       real(kind=8), intent(inout) :: vec_out(this%nrow)
       integer, optional, intent(inout) :: info
       integer, optional, intent(in   ) :: lun_err
     end subroutine multiplication

  end interface
  !>---------------------------------------------------------
  !> Structure variable for Identity matrix
  !> (rectangular case included)
  !>---------------------------------------------------------
  type, extends(abs_linop), public :: eye
   contains
     !> Static constructor 
     procedure, public, pass :: init => init_eye
     !> Compute matrix times vector operatoration
     procedure, public,  pass :: Mxv => apply_eye
  end type eye


  !>----------------------------------------------------------------
  !> Structure variable to build implicit matrix defined
  !> as composition and sum of linear operator
  !>----------------------------------------------------------------
  public :: add_linop, operator(+)
  type, extends(abs_linop) :: add_linop
     class(abs_linop) , pointer :: matrix_1
     class(abs_linop) , pointer :: matrix_2
     real(kind=8), allocatable  :: scr(:)
   contains
     procedure, public , pass:: Mxv => add_Mxv
  end type add_linop

  INTERFACE OPERATOR (+)
     module PROCEDURE mmsum
  END INTERFACE OPERATOR (+)
 
contains 
  !>------------------------------------------------------
  !> Function that give two linear operator A1 and A2
  !> defines, implicitely, the linear operator
  !> A=A1+A2
  !> (public procedure for class add_linop)
  !> 
  !> usage:
  !>     'var' = A1 + A2
  !<-------------------------------------------------------------
  function mmsum(matrix_1,matrix_2) result(this)
    implicit none
    class(abs_linop), target, intent(in) :: matrix_1
    class(abs_linop), target, intent(in) :: matrix_2
    type(add_linop) :: this
    ! local
    integer :: res
    character(len=20) :: n1,n2

    if (matrix_1%nrow .ne. matrix_2%nrow)  &
         write(*,*) 'Error mmproc dimension must agree '
    if (matrix_1%ncol .ne. matrix_2%ncol)  &
         write(*,*) 'Error mmproc dimension must agree '


    this%matrix_1 => matrix_1
    this%matrix_2 => matrix_2
    
    this%nrow = matrix_1%nrow
    this%ncol = matrix_2%ncol

    this%name=etb(matrix_1%name)//'+'//etb(matrix_2%name)
    
    write(*,*) 'Sum Matrix initialization '    
    write(*,*) 'M1  : ',this%matrix_1%name
    write(*,*) 'M2  : ',this%matrix_2%name
    write(*,*) 'sum : ',this%name
    
    allocate(this%scr(this%nrow),stat=res)
  contains
    function etb(strIn) result(strOut)
      implicit none
      ! vars
      character(len=*), intent(in) :: strIn
      character(len=len_trim(adjustl(strIn))) :: strOut

      strOut=trim(adjustl(strIn))
    end function etb
  end function mmsum

  recursive subroutine add_Mxv(this,vec_in,vec_out,info,lun_err)
    implicit none
    class(add_linop),  intent(inout) :: this
    real(kind=8), intent(in   ) :: vec_in(this%ncol)
    real(kind=8), intent(inout) :: vec_out(this%nrow)
    integer, optional, intent(inout) :: info
    integer, optional, intent(in   ) :: lun_err

    write(*,*) 'Matrix vector multipliction',&
         'matrix:',this%name,&
         'M1: ',this%matrix_1%name,&
         'M2: ',this%matrix_2%name
    select type (mat=>this%matrix_1)
    type is (add_linop)
       write(*,*) 'is allocated(mat%scr) ?', allocated(mat%scr)
    end select
    
    call this%matrix_1%Mxv(vec_in,this%scr,info=info,lun_err=lun_err)
    call this%matrix_2%Mxv(vec_in,vec_out,info=info,lun_err=lun_err)
    vec_out = this%scr + vec_out
  end subroutine add_Mxv

  
  subroutine  init_eye(this,nrow)
    implicit none
    class(eye),      intent(inout) :: this
    integer,         intent(in   ) :: nrow
     this%nrow = nrow
    this%ncol = nrow
  end subroutine init_eye
  
  subroutine apply_eye(this,vec_in,vec_out,info,lun_err)
    class(eye),   intent(inout) :: this
    real(kind=8), intent(in   ) :: vec_in(this%ncol)
    real(kind=8), intent(inout) :: vec_out(this%nrow)
    integer, optional, intent(inout) :: info
    integer, optional, intent(in   ) :: lun_err
    ! local
    integer :: mindim

    vec_out = vec_in    
    if (present(info)) info=0

  end subroutine apply_eye


  



end module LinearOperator




program main
  use LinearOperator
  implicit none
  real(kind=8) :: x(2),y(2),z(2),t(2)
  type(eye) :: id1,id2,id3
  type(add_linop) :: sum12,sum23,sum123_ok,sum123_ko 
  integer :: i
  call id1%init(2)
  id1%name='I1'
  call id2%init(2)
  id2%name='I2'
  call id3%init(2)
  id3%name='I3'
  x=1.0d0
  y=1.0d0
  z=1.0d0

  write(*,*) ' Vector x =', x
  call id1%Mxv(x,t)
  write(*,*) ' Vector t = I1 *x', t

  write(*,*) ' '

  sum12 = id1 + id2
  call sum12%Mxv(x,t)
  write(*,*) ' Vector t = (I1 +I2) *x', t

  write(*,*) ' '

  sum23 = id2 + id3
  sum123_ok = id1 + sum23
  call sum123_ok%Mxv(x,t)
  write(*,*) ' Vector t = ( I1 + (I2 + I3) )*x', t


  write(*,*) ' '
  sum123_ko = id1 + id2 + id3
  call sum123_ko%Mxv(x,t)
  write(*,*) ' Vector t = ( I1 +I2 + I3) *x', t
end program main
```

I compile this code with gfortran version 7.5.0  and flags
"-g -C -Wall -fcheck=all -O -ffree-line-length-none -mcmodel=medium "
and this is what I get

```
  Vector x =   1.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000     
  Vector t = I1 *x   1.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000     
  
 Sum Matrix initialization 
 M1  : I1                  
 M2  : I2                  
 sum : I1+I2               
 Matrix vector multiplictionmatrix:I1+I2               M1: I1                  M2: I2                  
  Vector t = (I1 +I2) *x   2.0000000000000000        2.0000000000000000     
  
 Sum Matrix initialization 
 M1  : I2                  
 M2  : I3                  
 sum : I2+I3               
 Sum Matrix initialization 
 M1  : I1                  
 M2  : I2+I3               
 sum : I1+I2+I3            
 Matrix vector multiplictionmatrix:I1+I2+I3            M1: I1                  M2: I2+I3               
 Matrix vector multiplictionmatrix:I2+I3               M1: I2                  M2: I3                  
  Vector t = ( I1 + (I2 + I3) )*x   3.0000000000000000        3.0000000000000000     
  
 Sum Matrix initialization 
 M1  : I1                  
 M2  : I2                  
 sum : I1+I2               
 Sum Matrix initialization 
 M1  : I1+I2               
 M2  : I3                  
 sum : I1+I2+I3            
 Matrix vector multiplictionmatrix:I1+I2+I3            M1: I1+I2               M2: I3                  
 is allocated(mat%scr) ? F
 Matrix vector multiplictionmatrix:I1+I2               M1: I1                  M2: I2                  
At line 126 of file LinearOperator.f90
Fortran runtime error: Allocatable actual argument 'this' is not allocated
```

Everthing works fine when I use the (+) operator with 2 terms. But when 3 terms are used there is an issue with the allocatable array scr, member of type (add_linop), that is not allocated.

Does anybody knows the reason of this issue and how to solve it?
I include the Makefile used for compiling the code.

```
#Gfortran compiler
FC            = gfortran
OPENMP        = -fopenmp
MODEL         = -mcmodel=medium
OFLAGS        = -O5 -ffree-line-length-none
DFLAGS        = -g -C -Wall -fcheck=all -O -ffree-line-length-none
#DFLAGS        = -g -C -Wall -ffree-line-length-none -fcheck=all
PFLAGS        = -pg
CPPFLAGS      = -D_GFORTRAN_COMP
ARFLAGS       =

ODIR          = objs
MDIR          = mods
LDIR          = libs

INCLUDE       = -J$(MODDIR)

OBJDIR        = $(CURDIR)/$(ODIR)
MODDIR        = $(CURDIR)/$(MDIR)
LIBDIR        = $(CURDIR)/$(LDIR)

INCLUDE       += -I$(MODDIR)

FFLAGS        = $(OFLAGS) $(MODEL)  $(INCLUDE) 

LIBSRCS       = 

DEST          = .

EXTHDRS       =

HDRS          =

LIBS          = -llapack -lblas

LIBMODS       = 

LDFLAGS       = $(MODEL)  $(INCLUDE) -L. -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L$(LIBDIR)

LINKER        = $(FC)

MAKEFILE      = Makefile

PRINT         = pr

CAT       = cat

PROGRAM       = main.out

SRCS          = LinearOperator.f90 

OBJS          = LinearOperator.f90 

PRJS= $(SRCS:jo=.prj)

OBJECTS        = $(SRCS:%.f90=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

MODULES        = $(addprefix $(MODDIR)/,$(MODS))

.SUFFIXES: .prj .f90

print-%  : 
        @echo $* = $($*)

.f.prj:
    ftnchek -project -declare -noverbose $<

.f90.o:
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c  $< 

all::       
        @make dirs
        @make $(PROGRAM) 

$(PROGRAM):     $(LIBS) $(MODULES) $(OBJECTS)
        $(LINKER) -o $(PROGRAM) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

$(LIBS):
        @set -e; for i in $(LIBSRCS); do cd $$i; $(MAKE) --no-print-directory -e CURDIR=$(CURDIR); cd $(CURDIR); done


$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.f90 
        $(FC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(FFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

dirs: 
        @-mkdir -p $(OBJDIR) $(MODDIR) $(LIBDIR)

clean-emacs:
        @-rm -f $(CURDIR)/*.*~ 
        @-rm -f $(CURDIR)/*\#* 

check: $(PRJS)
    ftnchek -noverbose -declare $(PRJS) -project -noextern -library > $(PROGRAM).ftn

profile:;       @make "FFLAGS=$(PFLAGS) $(MODEL) " "CFLAGS=$(PFLAGS) $(MODEL)" "LDFLAGS=$(PFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)" $(PROGRAM)

debug:;         @make "FFLAGS=$(DFLAGS) $(MODEL) $(INCLUDE)" "LDFLAGS=$(DFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)" $(PROGRAM)

openmp:;         @make "FFLAGS=$(OFLAGS) $(OPENMP) $(MODEL) $(INCLUDE)" "LDFLAGS=$(LDFLAGS) $(OPENMP)" $(PROGRAM)

clean:;     @rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(MODULES) $(PROGRAM).cat $(PROGRAM).ftn
        @set -e; for i in $(LIBSRCS); do cd $$i; $(MAKE) --no-print-directory clean; cd $(CURDIR); done

clobber:;   @rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(MODULES) $(PROGRAM).cat $(PROGRAM).ftn $(PROGRAM)
        @-rm -rf $(OBJDIR) $(MODDIR) $(LIBDIR)
        @-rm -f $(CURDIR)/*.*~ 
        @-rm -f $(CURDIR)/*\#* 

.PHONY:     mods

index:;     ctags -wx $(HDRS) $(SRCS)

install:    $(PROGRAM)
        install -s $(PROGRAM) $(DEST)

print:;     $(PRINT) $(HDRS) $(SRCS)

cat:;       $(CAT) $(HDRS) $(SRCS) > $(PROGRAM).cat

program:        $(PROGRAM)

profile:        $(PROFILE)

tags:           $(HDRS) $(SRCS); ctags $(HDRS) $(SRCS)

update:     $(DEST)/$(PROGRAM)

main.o: linearoperator.mod
# DO NOT EDIT --- auto-generated file
linearoperator.mod : LinearOperator.f90
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c $<
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not valid Fortran.

The function result of `mmsum` has a pointer component which, during the execution of the function, is pointer associated with a dummy argument.  This dummy argument (correctly for this use) has the target attribute.  However, the actual argument does not have the target attribute: when the function execution completes the pointer component [becomes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31345009/3157076) of undefined pointer association status.

In the subroutine `add_Mxv` there is an attempt to dereference this pointer.  This is not allowed.

It will be necessary to revisit how the operands are handled in your data type.  Note in particular that an expression cannot have the target attribute: in the case of `id1+id2+id3` the `id1+id2` expression won't usefully remain as something to reference later on.

Comment: Thank your your help. I will try to figure it out in other way. Regarding the discussion in here [https://stackoverflow.com/q/31345009/3157076] . Is there a proper way to associate a pointer which is a component of derived type within a type bound procedure?

Comment: As long as the pointer _target_ remains valid, pointer assignment of a component isn't a problem.  Where the approach of this question fails is that the operands _aren't_ (or don't remain as) valid pointer targets.